# Connect Power Virtual Agents with PowerBI report and query through PVA BOT

Tags: powerbi, bots, power-automate, power-virtual-agents

My requirement : Create a Power Virtual Agent (PVA) and integrate PowerBI report - from PVA I want to ask report based questions like 1. What is the max sales amount?, 2. Who has made maximum sales, 3. Which product is most sold etc?

Yet to try a solution yet.

Comment: @horseyride, thank you for stopping by to comment. I am new to PVA and am working my way to learn, have started with the basics  FLOW a bit. Posted my requirement to pick up some help to replicate faster.